# How would I fix an under extrusion problem?

Tags: underextrusion, ender3

Hey all I have an Ender 3 V1 and I have a problem with it under extruding. Its not putting out enough PLA to stick and it just becomes a mess. (Bed has a magnetic PEI plate that only has a few uses) Occasionally it will put out a little more on one side or another and it would stick, or the first few layers would stick but just be super thin, and then the next layers wouldnt stick at all. I initially just thought it was that the bed was too far away from the nozzle, that wasnt it. I Releveled the bed but that wasnt it. Speeds, temp and everything seem fine when it was printing good, I messed with them a little but it had little effect. I did a cold pull and still no change. Replaced nozzle completely and it started printing great again. I printed probably 8 or 10 things flawlessly. Using the printer at least daily. I stopped printing for about a week or so and when i went back to printing it proceeded to do the same thing. Is there an easy fix for this? Anuy suggestions would be great! Appreciate it in Advance.

Comment: Hello Nick, you need to publish one or two images about your under extrusion, there are several parameters or mechanic adjustments to fix the problem.